# created sorted table in gtk

Tags: python, user-interface, uitableview, gtk, pygtk

What's the easieest way to create a sorted table view in gtk? I'm not sure if that's the right term, but you know the one:

[image: sorted table image]
<sub>(source: [sun.com](http://java.sun.com/products/jlf/at/book/images/sort_cmyk.gif))</sub>

Is there a built-in widget for this? If not, how would I go about making those columns that look slightly different, click to change sorting, etc. Note I don't need multi-column sorting at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sorted List Stores](https://web.archive.org/web/20100726094009/http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-TreeModelInterface.html#sec-SortingTreeModelRows)

UPDATE:

After looking at your edit (disregarding commens):

- There is no built-in widget, but ListView = TreeView + ListStore
- Clicking to change sorting is harder, but probably not by much

Remember that most anything is handled by their tutorial, at PyGTK.org [(HTML)](https://web.archive.org/web/20100819160001/http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/index.html)
and in [PDF Format](https://web.archive.org/web/20100619012353/http://www.pygtk.org/dist/pygtk2-tut.pdf). They also have a [PyGTK Refrence](https://web.archive.org/web/20100815063821/http://www.pygtk.org/reference.html), if that suits you better.

Comment: ah looks about right, I'll look into it. why's that stuff called TreeModel and such ?

Comment: That's the generic ListStore and TreeStore interface. That's what TreeViews load their items from.

Comment: i mean why's it called a TreeView if it's just a list of items I'm viewing? I guess a list is just a flat tree..

Comment: Yes, it's just for simplicity. Although, in my opionion, ListStore is just as much a hack as any ListView control would be.